# Automator's new Quick Action doesn't work

Tags: macos, automator

I tried creating a Quick Action using Automator in macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F203), but it doesn't show up at all:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Is there anything else I need to do to enable it?

Comment: Is it enabled in the Services Preferences?

Comment: Where exactly should it be enabled?

Comment: You can check if the service is enabled from the **AppName > Services > Services Preferences** menu item or **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services**.

Comment: It doesn't show up there either.

Comment: Automator normally saves service workflows in **~/Library/Services**, which is where the system looks for them.  The workflow will need to be relocated to that folder if you saved it somewhere else.

Comment: I think it was caused by the fact that I have that folder symlinked. But I have other "old-style" workflows there that work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't work if the `~/Library/Services` is a symbolic link.

But, if you add the workflow to the directory `~/Library/Services`, double click it, and then replace back the directory with a symlink, it keeps working, even if you make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this command did the job but I have to run everytime a new Quick Action is added :

/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -flush